# Merging arrays that are inside a foreach loop using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ALFA01
    [1] => BETA02
    [2] => GAMMA03
    [3] => DELTA04
    [4] => EPSILON05
    [5] => ZETA06
    [6] => THETA07
    [7] => IOTA08
    [8] => KAPPA09
    [9] => LAMBDA10
)
```

Then I separate the values into characters and numbers in the following way:

```
foreach($portfolio as $value) {
    $char = substr("$value", 0, 2);
    $numb = substr("$value", 2);
```

and do a query using this values:

```
    $query = "
        SELECT id, typ1, typ2, typ3
        FROM data_table
        WHERE char = '$char'
        AND numb = $numb
        LIMIT 1";

    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);

    //Now we have some important variables that will help finding our result.
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $typ1 = $row['typ1'];
        $typ2 = $row['typ2'];
        $typ3 = $row['typ3'];
    }
```

Then I do some queries in case typ* are = 1 (it can be only 0 or 1).

```
if ($typ1 == 1) {
    $query_id_num2 = "
        SELECT id_num2
        FROM values_table01
        WHERE id_num1 = $id";
    $result_id_num2 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query_id_num2);

    // Return an array with all ids.
    $id_num2_typ01 = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_appln_id_num2)) {
        $id_num2_typ01[] = ($row['id_num2']);
    }
}
```

/== EDIT ==/

In each different typ we have a different values_table.
I'm now writing the complete query for typ2, so it will be emphasised.

// == /EDIT ==/

Then I do the same to typ2 and typ3...

```
if ($typ2 == 1) {
    $query_id_num2 = "
        SELECT id_num2
        FROM values_table02
        WHERE id_num1 = $id";
    $result_id_num2 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query_id_num2);

    // Return an array with all ids.
    $id_num2_typ02 = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_appln_id_num2)) {
        $id_num2_typ02[] = ($row['id_num2']);
    }
}
```

etc.

In the end I merge the three arrays (if they are set) and print the result on the screen:

```
// typ01
if (isset($id_num2_typ01)){
    $id_num2_typ01 = $id_num2_typ01;
} else {
    $id_num2_typ01 = array();
}

// typ02
if (isset($id_num2_typ02)){
    $id_num2_typ02 = $id_num2_typ02;
} else {
    $id_num2_typ02 = array();
}

// typ03
if (isset($id_num2_typ03)){
    $id_num2_typ03 = $id_num2_typ03;
} else {
    $id_num2_typ03 = array();
}

// merge arrays
$id_num2 = array_merge($id_num2_typ01,$id_num2_typ02,$id_num2_typ03);

// print it on screen
echo '<pre>id_num2:<br />';
print_r($appln_idNum2);
echo '</pre>';

} // this closes the above foreach, i.e. the code will loop to every value of the first array
```

As result I receive for example following data:

```
id_num2:
Array
(
    [0] => 41558194
    [1] => 44677841
    [2] => 44503689
    [3] => 40651770
    [4] => 41667291
)

id_num2:
Array
(
    [0] => 15458354
    [1] => 35477154
    [2] => 15703123
    [3] => 95151111
    [4] => 55567125
)

etc.
```

In our case we will have 10 small arrays like that.

My problem is: How can I merge this small arrays so in the ende I have only one array?

Maybe is there also another possibility to write the code to be better and more efficient.

Comment: why don't you do it all in the intitial `while` loop and just create one array?

Comment: Hello @charlierfl, thank for your question. But what you mean? Could you please show me an example?

Comment: I cannot do that because we have diferent table for each typ. I will edit my text to emphasise this.

Comment: If you want efficiency, all of this code can be done using 2 SQL queries if you use  `WHERE (char = '$char' AND numb = $numb) OR (char = '$char' AND numb = $numb)` without `LIMIT 1` and then `UNION` to combine all the `SELECT id_numx FROM values_table_x` queries. This will also solve the merging issue because there would only be 1 SQL response.

Answer (score 0):

This code should give you 1 array. I can't test it since I don't know the database. It will query all the values from `data_table` and use the result to generate a big `UNION` query for the other tables. Then use `mysqli_fetch_column` the fetch the `id_num2` column into 1 array.

Try it out let me know if it works

```
$portfolio = ['ALFA01', 'BETA02', 'GAMMA03', 'DELTA04', 'EPSILON05', 'ZETA06', 'THETA07', 'IOTA08', 'KAPPA09', 'LAMBDA10',];
$where = [];

foreach($portfolio as $value) {
    list($char, $numb) = preg_split('/\D+\K/', $value);
    $where[] = "(char = '$char' AND numb = $numb)";
}

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, 'SELECT id, typ1, typ2, typ3 FROM data_table WHERE '.implode(' OR ',$where));

$queries = [];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    foreach(['1','2','3'] as $n) {
        if($row["typ$n"] == 1) {
            $queries[] = "SELECT id_num2 FROM values_table0$n WHERE id_num1 = ".$row['id'];
        }
    }
}

$result_all = mysqli_query($mysqli, implode(' UNION ',$queries));
$id_num_all = mysqli_fetch_column($result_all);

print_r($id_num_all);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a prepared statement to pass in your portfolio values as a matter of modern, secure, stable querying practices.
2. Use `UNION` to consolidate the 3 `values` tables then `JOIN` that data payload to your `data_table`.
3. You don't need to use PHP to split each portfolio into `char` and `numb` variables.  You can instead design your `WHERE` clause to `CONCAT` those database columns into a portfolio string.
4. Make just 1 trip to the database
5. Use PHP to group your result set on the portfolio ids. If you were using PDO, this step could be handled differently.

Code: ([PHPize.online Demo](https://phpize.online/s/IC))

```
$portfolios = [
    'ALFA01',
    'BETA02',
    'GAMMA03',
    'DELTA04',
    'EPSILON05',
    'ZETA06',
];

$placeholders = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($portfolios), '?'));

$sql = <<<SQL
SELECT data.id,
       values_table.id_num2 AS val
FROM data_table AS data
JOIN (
      SELECT 1 AS typ_num, id_num1, id_num2 FROM values_table01
      UNION
      SELECT 2 AS typ_num, id_num1, id_num2 FROM values_table02
      UNION
      SELECT 3 AS typ_num, id_num1, id_num2 FROM values_table03
     ) AS values_table
     ON values_table.id_num1 = data.id
        AND (
             (values_table.typ_num = 1 AND data.typ1 = 1)
             OR (values_table.typ_num = 2 AND data.typ2 = 1)
             OR (values_table.typ_num = 3 AND data.typ3 = 1)
            )
WHERE CONCAT(`char`,numb) IN ($placeholders)
SQL;

$result = [];
foreach ($mysqli->execute_query($sql, $portfolios) as $row) {
    $result[$row['id']][] = $row['val'];
}
var_export($result);
```